# FileUpload in primefaces5

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem with primefaces specifically related p:fileUpload. The problem is that I can't identify in the method to load each file (like handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) ) is last file on the list of files when charging multiple files. is possible? how? I need help. I need know this because i need close 'addfile' dialog when charge the last file.

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
...
}

<p:dialog header="#{text['tasksbacking.attach.addFile']}" 
          widgetVar="addfile"
          height="500"
          width="500"
          closeOnEscape="false" 
          closable="false"
          resizable="false" 
          draggable="false"                                            
          fitViewport="true"
          modal="true" 
          appendTo="@(body)">
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addFileDialog">
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{attachmentsComponent.handleFileUpload}" 
                      mode="advanced" multiple="true" dragDropSupport="true" 
                      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|txt|xml)$/"
                      update=":#{cc.clientId}:formAttachForm:attachTree"/>
    </h:form>

</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Did you try using `oncomplete` event on p:fileupload? e.g.:`oncomplete=PF('addfile').close()`

Comment: perfect Pellizon, but not is .close() is .hide() :D

added this code in p:fileUpload
oncomplete="PF('addfile').hide();"

Comment: You're welcome! I just don't know why the close() is not working...if you need an extra help on that, let me know. --- Please, mark my answer as the correct answer

Comment: because in Client Side API for widget Dialog just have 2 methods show and hide (Primefaces 5)

Comment: Oops! You're right, just checked! =)

Answer (score 1):

the answer is:
added code in p:fileUpload oncomplete="PF('addfile').hide();"

thanks @Pellizon

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `oncomplete` event to trigger some action after the upload event.

In your case, if you want to close the dialog, you could use Hide() or Close() events of p:dialog

Example:

```
<p:fileUpload .... oncomplete="PF('addfile').hide()"
```